# What does the "Activation Event" do for server-side Google Optimize experiments?

Tags: google-optimize

In normal A/B tests with Google Optimize, the `Activation Event` controls when the experiment applies to the users' experience.  However, with server-side tests, the *application itself* determines when the experiment applies and then reports back to Optimize.

So what exactly does the "Activation Event" mean to server-side tests?  Does it even matter?

For a more detailed explanation of what I'm looking for, consider the following web application:

```
<html>
  ...
  <head>
    <script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];</script>
    <script>This script loads in Google Optimize asynchronously</script>
    <script>This script loads in GTM asynchronously</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <script>This script is loaded asynchronously for some users and pushes `experiment_id.variant_id` to the datalayer</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's undesirable to have to fiddle around with the exact order that things are loaded in the `<head>` element, but we're seeing that unless the experiment is pushed to the datalayer before loading in GTM / Optimize, tracking isn't working.  I'm assuming that this is because the optimize experiment is set to activate on the `PageView` tag.  `PageView` is in a race condition with the web application.

Could we perhaps simply change the activation event to something that the web application controls to avoid this race condition?